# Django, check if exists but on many items from an array of properties

Tags: django

```
arr = [
{id: 1, filename: "a"},
{id: 2, filename: "b"},
]
```

If I wanted to check if a Django table has 2 items with properties corresponding to the above, I could do:

```
for n in arr:
    e = MyTable.objects.filter(id=n["id"], filename=n["filename"]).exists()
    if not e: # raise error
```

But this requires to do one query for each item in the array.

How can I do this in a single query?

I was thinking to chain `Q`s like this:

```
Q(id=n['id'],filename=n['filename']) | Q(id=n['id'],filename=n['filename']) | ...for each item in array
```

But then how I could I check if each separate Q returns at least one entry?

I don't care about looping over arr as long as I don't do a query for each iteration.

Comment: Each `{ ... }` has a *distinct* `id`?

Comment: Yes: we can assume that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment, the items in `arr` all have a *distinct* `id`, so we can count the number of items that satisfy this condition. We know that this should be the same as the number of dictionaries in `arr`, since each `Q(id=..., ...)` can satisfy at most one record:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

MyTable.objects.filter(
    reduce(or_, [Q(id=n['id'],filename=n['filename']) for n in arr])
).count() == len(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a list of all the `ids` and `filenames`, then use `__in`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#in

```
ids = [item.get('id') for item in arr]
filenames = [item.get('filename') for item in arr]
qs = MyTable.objects.filter(id__in=ids, filename__in=filenames)
assert qs.count() == len(arr)
```

Comment: This will work only if it's not possible to have {id: 1, filename: "b"} item. But it will be faster than Willem Van Onsem answer (i guess).

Comment: @IgorBekov: I think it will work, if the `filename`s can be distributed differently, so that for example the filenames of two items can be swapped. GIven that constraint it works, otherwise, it might fail. So I would advice Gaurav to add a note about this to the answer, then it is, under these assumptions, a valid answer.